# How can i store data in sharedpreferences for 23 hour in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Explanation:
           In my application token will change after every 24 hours.so, i want to store old data for 23 hour in sharedpreferences ok i did it. Now if more than 23 hours passed my new authentication token will replace my new data in sharedpreference. It means my token will work for next 23 hour.

How can i check my 23 hours passed from my first authentication time?

Here is my code to get the token and save into sharedpreference

```
 private void Authentication_App_Service(String responseStr) {
        int hours=0;
        int minutes=0;
        try {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            Log.e("HOUR OF DAY",""+hours);
            minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jobj_res = new JSONObject(responseStr);

            String status = jobj_res.getString("status");
            String status_code = jobj_res.getString("status_code");
            statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status_code);

            if (status.equals("True") || status.equals("true")) {

                JSONObject a_res = jobj_res.getJSONObject("auth");
                main_public_access_token = a_res.getString("access_token");
                SharedPreferences sharedTimer=this.getSharedPreferences("SaveTime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedTimer.edit();
                editor.putString("accessToken", main_public_access_token);
                editor.putInt("authentication_time", hours);
                editor.commit();

            } else {
                dialog_popup();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("checking value >> ", ""+ main_public_access_token);
        if(main_public_access_token.equals("")){
            dialog_popup();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(key_access_token, main_public_access_token);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Above method will run at every 23 hour.Before 23 hour this method will not called again.

I use my token from sharedpreference before 23 hours.
Please help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: how you are getting token after 24 hours?

Comment: my token change after every 24 hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AlarmManager for  this.Set it repeating for every 23 hours.
Use following code

```
   //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                23 * 60 * 60 * 1000,pendingIntent);
```

Above written code will fire an intent after every 23 hours.Let me know if you want more explanation.Mark this up if it helps.

Comment: In above code AlarmManager class calls RingAlarm Class after every 23 hours even if the Application is closed.So you can do the required operation in RingAlarm class

Comment: if my application is closed.then its call after 23 hours?

Comment: Yes,it will fire an intent to RingAlarm class even if the App is closed..let me know if you still face any issue in using it..I will help you out

Comment: if i want to check this method fro ever 15 minutes then what will i need to change in your post?

Comment: How can i implement according to my problem?

Comment: in my post you have to give time into milliseconds so for 23 hours i have given 23*60*60*1000. For 15 minutes you have to change the milliseconds to 15*60*1000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106187/discussion-between-milan-gajera-and-hardeep).

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the same task after some time use Timer with simple & sorted method

```
private TimerTask doAsynchronousTask;

public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        //final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {                 
                try {

                    // Write Your code here
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, (23*60*60*1000)); //execute in every 23 Hrs

    }
```

Comment: Suppose, more than 23 hour have been passed then your post work or not?

Comment: yes. it works but, after all, dependency is on The Internet connectivity how your code is implemented.It will work in background application is running or not